# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol in function

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm using VS2008 WinCE7. I'm facing linking error during build.

The file system structure is

```
menu.c - ./menu.c
eboot.h - ./eboot.h
file_1.cpp - ./dir1/file_1.cpp
```

where `.` represents current directory

**menu.c**

```
#include <eboot.h>

static VOID OALWriteToEMMC(OAL_BLMENU_ITEM *pMenu);

VOID OALWriteToEMMC(OAL_BLMENU_ITEM *pMenu)
{
     OALTestEMMC();
}
```

**file_1.cpp**

```
#include <eboot.h>

VOID OALTestEMMC();

VOID OALTestEMMC()
{
//some code
}
```

**eboot.h**

```
 VOID OALTestEMMC();
```

I'm getting the error

```
menu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol OALTestEMMC referenced in function OALWriteToEMMC
```

Please guide me how to solve it.

**EDIT1:**

**menu.c**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" VOID OALTestEMMC();
#endif
```

and removed the declaration in `eboot.h` and added it in `file_1.cpp`
But, the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are compiling the function definition in C++ but the use of that function in C. Without making the function `extern "C"` in C++, the compiler will *mangle* the name, and generate a symbol that won't match the declaration used in the C code.

If you want to mix C and C++, make sure that the declarations in C++ are marked `extern "C"` so that the compiler won't mangle the names and will use the C calling conventions. Alternatively, compile everything in C++ (or in C)

Comment: I tried it as mentioned in EDIT1. But, the error persists. Also, I tried it differently as in original post before edit. That also didn't work.

Comment: @Gomu: you got it the wrong way. You need to instruct the C++ compiler processing `file_1.cpp` not to mangle. The C compiler processing `menu.c` is not going to mangle. The usual approach would be adding that code to the header, where it can be shared by all translation units that use that function.

Comment: Ok. So, I added that three line of code in `eboot.h`. Now, I'm getting a lot of linking errors for all the functions in `file_1.cpp` file.

Comment: If the `menu.c` is in the same directory as in `file_1.cpp`, then there is no error while compiling. But, I'm not supposed to move that file. What else can be tried?

Comment: @Gomu: You are not providing enough information. How are you linking the different object files? How are you compiling (maybe you are forcing the compiler to compile as C++ the menu.c file regardless of the extension)...

Comment: Actually file_1.cpp will form a library. I had not included that to the sources of menu.c. Now, I had included it and it is compiling without linker errors. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gomu: To be able to handle that error you need to provide more information, and fix anything in the question that does not map to your real code. In particular, what is the command line you pass the linker, what is the complete error message you are getting (does it not contain more detail than what you posted?) Did you add the `extern "C"` in the C++ side? In the header?

Answer (score 1):

David Rodríguez's original answer is correct. You are invoking a C++ function (OALTestEMMC) from a C source file. As David mentioned, the C++ compiler will [mangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) the function name. In order to suppress the name mangling so that the code in menu.c can invoke it, place the 'extern "C"' qualifier on the OALTestEMMC function (in file_1.cpp):

```
extern "C" VOID OALTestEMMC();

extern "C" VOID OALTestEMMC() {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining with illustration!

Comment: Is file_1.obj being included in the list of files that the linker is using? Can you include the contents of the ./sources file?